# approximate unit of $K(H)$- ordering on $K(H)$ and finite rank operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i:i\in I\}$ . Consider the $C^\ast$-algebra of the compact operators on $H$, $K(H)$.
For a finite subset $F\subseteq I$, let $P_F$ be the orthogonal projection onto $span\{e_i:i\in F\}$. In an exercise one has to show, that $(P_F)$ is an approximate unit of $K(H)$. This is the background of the follwing questions:

$(P_F)$ has to be monotonically increasing, but what is a partial ordering on $K(H)$ ? If $F, S$ are finite subsets of $I$, such that $F\subseteq S$, it has to be $P_F\le P_S$. I know that $span\{e_i:i\in F\}\subset span\{e_i:i\in S\}$ but I dont know, what $P_F\le P_S$ means.

If you want to prove, that $\|TP_F-T\|\to 0$ and $\|P_FT-T\|\to 0$ for all $T\in K(H)$, it suffices to show, that $\|AP_F-A\|\to 0$ and $\|P_FA-A\|\to 0$ for all $A\in F(H)$, where $F(H)$ is the set of all finite rank operators on $H$. My question: I have a solution of this claim which says that is it possible to express $A$ as follows: $A=\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_{x_k,y_k}$ with $\theta_{x_k,y_k}(z)=x_k\langle y_k,z\rangle$ for all $x_k,y_k,z\in H$, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-rank_operator . Then if you know that $\|P_FA-A\|\to 0$, how to prove $\|AP_F-A\|\to 0$? Is the following correct: $\|AP_F-A\|=\|(AP_F-A)^*\|=\|P_FA^*-A^*\|\to 0$? I think here we need, that $F(H)$ is closed under taking adjoints, is it true?
Regards.

Comment: For operators $A,B\in B(H)$, $A\geq B$ means that $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq \langle Bx,x\rangle$ for all $x\in H$. In your case, this follows from the fact that $$\sum_{i\in F}|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{j\in S} |\langle x,e_j\rangle|^2 $$

Comment: Also see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923634/show-that-every-compact-operator-on-banach-space-is-a-norm-limit-of-finite-rank

Comment: ok thanks. But is $F(H)$ closed under taking adjoints? I'm not sure

Comment: Have you tried proving it? Begin by finding the adjoint of a rank one operator!